# It is possible to open a web page via AWS lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm curious whether is possible to load a web page via AWS lambda functions. 
I mean, I would like to open a webpage like www.something.com/home which makes a request to the AWS lambda function which will open/get resources from www.i-would-like-to-hide-this-url.com/home, but the URL should remain www.something.com/home.

So can I use AWS as a proxy for the case above?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with CloudFront using custom Origin. It will work as a reverse proxy for your customers.

> A custom origin is an HTTP server, for example, a web server. The HTTP server can be an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance or an HTTP server that you manage privately. An Amazon S3 origin configured as a website endpoint is also considered a custom origin.
>
> When you use a custom origin that is your own HTTP server, you specify the DNS name of the server, along with the HTTP and HTTPS ports and the protocol that you want CloudFront to use when fetching objects from your origin.

[Using Amazon EC2 or Other Custom Origins](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DownloadDistS3AndCustomOrigins.html#concept_CustomOrigin)

Or you can do it with ELB and a reverse proxy on EC2. But in this case you will be responsible for this reverse proxy.

Maybe it is even possible to do it with lambda if you code the "reverse proxy" solution, but I guess it is not exaclty recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you host the static assets (html/js/css/img) in S3, you front Lambda with API Gateway, and your web page makes HTTP/Rest requests to API Gateway which forwards them to your Lambda. Lambda itself does not typically serve the static assets. If you need SSL then you add CloudFront. Example [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/).